# pythonでscikit-learnを用いたらImportErrorが起きてしまいます

Tags: python, 機械学習, scikit-learn

技術評論社のデータサイエンティスト養成読本 機械学習入門編を読んでいます
128ページからscikit-learn入門のページが始まるのですが
そちらにあるコードを試したところ、scikit-learnのImportErrorが起きてしまいます

何が悪いのかわかりませんが・・・どなたかご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか？

Mac OSX 10.9
python 3.4.3

を使用しています。

sklearn.pyというファイルをpythonで実行してみた結果です

コード(sklearn.py)

```
# coding:utf-8

import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets

# 乱数によるデータを生成
np.random.seed(0)
regdata = datasets.make_regression(100, 1, noise=20.0)

# 学習を行いモデルのパラメータを表示
lin = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lin.fit(regdata[0], regdata[1])
print("coef and intercept :", lin.coef_, lin.intercept_)
print("score :", lin.score(regdata[0], regdata[1]))

# グラフを描画
xr = [-2.5, 2.5]
plt.plot(xr, lin.coef_ * xr + lin.intercept_)
plt.scatter(regdata[0], regdata[1])

plt.show()
```

エラー

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sklearn.py", line 6, in <module>
from sklearn import datasets
File "/Users/hoge/programming/training/python/sklearn.py", line 6, in <module>
from sklearn import datasets
ImportError: cannot import name 'datasets'
```

Comment: 【追記】
pyenvを用いてanaconda3-2.3.0 をインストールしてやってみたところ、コードがうまく実行されました、何で解決したのかよくわかりませんが・・・

Answer (score 2):

このスクリプトは自分自身を `import` しようとしています。
`sklearn` という外部のライブラリから `import` する意図で、`from sklearn` と書かれていますが、自分のファイル名も `sklearn.py` なために自分を読み込んでしまうのです。

ファイル名を変更しましょう。

追記: モジュールがどこのファイルから import されているか確認するには、例えば以下のようにします。

```python
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__file__)
```

Comment: 今ファイル名をtraining.pyに変更してやってみました、エラーは減ったのですがImporErrorはまだでてしまうみたいです・・・

`Traceback (most recent call last):

File "training.py", line 5, in <module>

from sklearn import linear_model, datasets
ImportError: cannot import name 'linear_model'``

Comment: @YoheiK ええっと、そもそも sklearn パッケージはインストールされていますでしょうか？

Comment: $ pip install scikit-learn

を行うことでinstallしました、このあたりは本のやり方通りに行っています

Comment: 上にもコメントを追記しましたが、anaconda3-2.3.0をインストールしてpythonのglobalとして実行してみた結果うまく実行できました、コメントありがとうございました！
ただなぜうまく行ったのかよくわからないです・・・・

Comment: @YoheiK pip コマンドが python 2.x 用なのではないでしょうか？ `which pip` としてみると分かるかと思います。

Comment: 内容だけ消された sklearn.py が残っていたりしませんか？ import sklearn と print(sklearn.__file__) だけのスクリプトを実行するなどして、どこの sklearn が import されているのか確認しておいた方がよいと思います。

Comment: `which pip` としてみたところ、`/Users/hoge/.pyenv/shims/pip`とでてきました、これはpython2.x系なのかな・・・？一応pathは3.4で通していたと思うのですが

Comment: sklearn.pyが残ってたかどうかは確かに確認してないですね・・・ちょっと確認してみたいと思います!ありがとうございます！

Comment: `python -c "import sklearn; print(sklearn.__file__)"`を実行してみたのですが、`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`と出てくるだけでした・・・もしかしてインストールされていないのかな・・・

Comment: python に静的にリンクされているモジュールは `__file__` を持ちません。array モジュールなどがそうです。anaconda というのをインストールされたようですね。もしかしたら anaconda というのは sklearn を内蔵している python なのでは。そして、これを実行したのも anaconda なのではないでしょうか。