# ImportError: cannot import name Randomというエラーが出る

Tags: python, 機械学習, scikit-learn

sklearnでランダムフォレストを使おうとしているのですが,以下のエラーが出てきます。
まず簡単なものでやってみようと思い,ネットに出ているコードをそのまま使用しました。
どうしたらよいでしょうか。

#### コード

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

trainingdata = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [-1, -1], [-2, -2]]
traininglabel = [1, 1, -1, -1]
testdata = [[3, 3], [-3, -3]]

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(trainingdata, traininglabel)
output = model.predict(testdata)

for label in output: print label
```

#### ターミナルのエラー表示

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "estimation.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import cpu_count
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .pool import MemmapingPool
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/pool.py", line 23, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name Random
```

Comment: このコードがそのサイトに載っていたものそのものなのでしたら、コピペ元のURLを書いて引用とするのが良いような気がします。

Comment: [blue_birdさんの以前の質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32202/sklearn%E3%81%A7importerror-cannot-import-name-clone%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B)では`random.py`というファイルを自分で作成しているように見えるのですが、このファイルはまだ残っていますか？

Comment: 関連： ["Tweepy: ImportError: cannot import name Random" (本家StackOverflowでの質問です)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750961/tweepy-importerror-cannot-import-name-random)

Comment: 関連： [pythonでscikit-learnを用いたらImportErrorが起きてしまいます](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16947/python%E3%81%A7scikit-learn%E3%82%92%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89importerror%E3%81%8C%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)

Comment: @nekketsuuu 残っていました。（正確には一旦ファイル名を変更したのですが、新しくプログラムをこのファイル名で作成していました…くだらないミスをしていました）
コメントありがとうございました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

本家SOで似た症状に困っていたが解決した人がいました．
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750961/tweepy-importerror-cannot-import-name-random
この人によると，同じディレクトリ内に`random.py`という名前のファイルを置いていて，それを意図せず代わりにimportしていたのが原因だったとのことでした．
チェックしてみてください．

Comment: 既にコメントで回答されている方がいましたね．すみません．

Comment: ご指摘の通りでした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @okdshin あれは回答ではなく回答を得るための情報を探っていただけだったので、気になさらないでください。回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: @blue_bird スタック・オーバーフローでは、質問者さんの疑問が解消した場合、回答の左の方にある緑の旗をクリックすることで「回答を承認」することができます。承認は義務ではないのですが、もしよろしければお願いいたします。詳しくは[「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をご覧ください。